# For every set $A$, there exists a well ordered set $V$ such that there exists no surjection $\pi: A \rightarrow V$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am proving that for every set$ A$, there exists a well ordered set $X$ such that there exists no surjection $\pi : A \longrightarrow V$.

I think that's very simple, and so I think maybe I made some mistake. Here it is what I try:

By Cantor theorem I know that there exists no surjection between $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$, and, as for every set $X$, there exists a well order with domain $X$. There is no surjection between $A$ and the well ordered set $(\mathcal{P}(A),\leq_{\mathcal{P}(A)})$

Am I right?

Please correct me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is completely indecipherable. You use $X$ twice, and it's not clear whether or not you make an appeal to the axiom of choice (or the well-ordering principle), which is something that you really *shouldn't* do.

This is very similar to Hartogs theorem, only with surjections, and you can repeat the essence of the proof of Hartogs theorem, using prewellorderings of subsets of $A$ rather than well-orderings of subsets of $A$.

But a simpler proof would use Hartogs theorem, in the following way:

Note that if $A$ can be surjected onto $\alpha$, then $\alpha$ can be injected into $\mathcal P(A)$. So if $A$ can be mapped onto every ordinal, then every ordinal can be injectively mapped into $\mathcal P(A)$. But Hartogs theorem tells us that there is an ordinal $\alpha$ which cannot be injectively mapped into $\mathcal P(A)$, and therefore there is an ordinal that $A$ cannot be mapped surjectively onto. $\square$

(The theorem itself is due to Lindenbaum, but it first appeared in Sierpinski's book from 1948.)

Comment: "for every set X, there exists a well order with domain X" is the well-ordering principle as far as I know. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem

Comment: Yes, but this theorem does not need the axiom of choice. In fact it is the theorem we use to prove that if between any two non-empty sets there is a surjection (in one way or another) then the axiom of choice holds. If you prove this theorem using the axiom of choice, how will you be able to do it?

Comment: excuse me where I've used the axiom of choice?

Comment: Proving this with the axiom of choice is morally wrong. It would be like proving Hartogs theorem with the axiom of choice. It's not something that you're supposed to be doing, and if the book didn't specify that the axiom of choice is not supposed to come up in the proof, then the book is definitely missing a crucial line in the text.

Comment: Saying that every set can be well-ordered is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice. Fine, you haven't used the axiom of choice, you have used an equivalent of the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the detailed explanation, +1. I haven't heard of this Hartogs' theorem and when I google it the only things I find are things in complex analysis ... where can I read about it? EDIT: [related to this?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number)

Comment: I haven't seen this yet on the faculty, excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @Zubin: Yes, that's the correct link. You can also look at the OP's previous questions; or search in the set theory tags (or the axiom of choice tag) the word Hartogs on this very site.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, there is no surjection between $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$. It suffices to show that $\mathcal{P}(A)$ can be well-ordered. But the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the [Well-Ordering Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem), which states that *every* set can be well-ordered. In particular, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ can be well-ordered, so we are done.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This is ***definitely*** a question where the axiom of choice should not be used.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why not? Is it overkill?

Comment: No, this is a theorem used in choiceless contexts quite often. So using the axiom of choice to prove it is morally wrong.